# Object literal and method grouping

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Could someone tell me how to write the below in an "object-literal" fashion..

```
my.item('apple').suffix("is awesome")
// console.log >> apple is awesome
```

My attempt ... but it obviously doesn't work.

```
var my = {
    item:function(item){
        my.item.suffix = function(suffix){
            console.log(item, suffix);
        }
    }
};
```

(Sorry if the title is wrong. I'm not sure of the terminology)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the root problem that you're actually trying to solve? Why do you want to use an object-literal? What's wrong with the one-liner you show? And [read about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which your question is a very nice example of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var my = {
  thing: undefined,

  // sets the `thing` property of `my`,
  // then returns `my` for chaining
  item: function (t) {
    thing = t;
    return this;
  },

  // concatenates the `thing` property with the given
  // suffix and returns it as a string
  suffix: function (s) {
    return thing + ' ' + s;
  }
};

my.item('apple').suffix("is awesome");
//--> apple is awesome
```

Comment: That is called a "fluent interface". Here is another way: http://jsbin.com/rihesekine/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I think that answers it! Cheers @Mike

Comment: And now I know what it's called! Thanks @gearsdigital

Comment: It may be you know the answer, other visitors may not.

Comment: How could I rectify that? Perhaps I could change the title to something like.. "How do you write "fluent interface" code using object-literal notation?"

Comment: My comment was an addition @Mike answer, just to provide further informations to future visitors. Thats it.